# Drawing concentric circle : Inner circle should be filled

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Im trying to achieve a button shapped as[image]

This is the current code I'm trying . It achieves concentric circle but the outer one is filled instead. Help.

```
 CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, 
                CGRectMake(
                    rect.origin.x + 10, 
                    rect.origin.y + 10, 
                    rect.size.width - 20, 
                    rect.size.height - 20));
    CGContextSetFillColor(ctx, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]));
    CGContextEOFillPath(ctx);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make two contexts and fill only the inner circle

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef outer = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(outer, 1.5);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(outer, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(outer, CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + 5, rect.origin.y + 5, rect.size.width - 10, rect.size.height - 10));
    CGContextStrokePath(outer);

    CGContextRef inner = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(inner, 1.5);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(inner, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(inner, CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + 15, rect.origin.y + 15, rect.size.width - 30, rect.size.height - 30));
    CGContextFillPath(inner);
}
```

I have added padding of 5 units to outer context so that it looks like circle and not rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom view `drawRect:`

```
    CGContextSetLineWidth(outerCircleContext, 1.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(outerCircleContext, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);

    CGRect outerRectangle = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect) - 25, CGRectGetMidY(rect) - 25 , 50, 50);

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(outerCircleContext, outerRectangle);

    CGContextStrokePath(outerCircleContext);




    CGContextRef innerCircleContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(innerCircleContext, 1.0);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(innerCircleContext, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);

    CGRect innerRectangle = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect) - 20, CGRectGetMidY(rect) - 20 , 40, 40);

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(innerCircleContext, innerRectangle);

    CGContextFillPath(innerCircleContext);
```

Yo can also use `path` also.

Comment: this just gives me rounded rectangle.